# Android ndk out of memory issue

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk, out-of-memory

i am trying to do real time image processing in android using jni. I have a native method to decode image data and i call this method for every frame. After a few seconds later i get out of memory and my app terminats.

LOG OUTPUT:

```
12-03 20:54:19.780: E/dalvikvm-heap(8119): Out of memory on a 3686416-byte allocation.
```

MY NATIVE METHOD:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL  Java_net_oyunyazar_arcc_data_FrameManager_processImage(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray arr) {

    jint *convertedData;
    convertedData = (jint*)malloc((width*height) * sizeof(jint));

    jintArray result = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, width*height);


    jint y,x;
    jbyte grey;

    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
    jbyte *YUVData = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, arr, 0);

        for (y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (x = 0; x < width; x++){

                grey = YUVData[y * width + x];
                convertedData[y*width+x] =(jint) grey & 0xff;

            }
        }

    LOGD("Random [%d]",len);

    (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result, 0, (width*height),convertedData );

    free(convertedData);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, YUVData, (jbyte*)arr, 0);

    return result;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by releasing the parameters.

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, arr, YUVData, 0);
```

It works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as yours.

In your specific case, while you are using pixel (and probably bitmap) you can send a bitmap instead of your bytearray and modify it

```
void *pixel_bm;
int retValue;

AndroidBitmapInfo info;
if ((retValue = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) return 0;
if ((retValue = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixel_bm)) < 0) return 0;

// you can now read an write into pixel_bm

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
```

If you find a solution to correctly free a GetByteArrayElement result, I'm instrested by the solution !!!